# SAX : UTF-8 decoding / encoding fail

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, sax

I am using SAX for parsing and then writing to XML files.

Both the parsing and writing processes break the UTF encoding.

Sample XML in :

```
<AddressInfo>
    <City name="Antalya" code="07">
      <District name="Döşemealtı">
        <Zip code="01680" />
      </District>
    </City>
<AddressInfo>
```

results in :

```
 <AddressInfo>
    <City name="Antalya" code="07">
        <District name="DÃ¶ÅŸemealtÄ±">
            <Zip code="01680"/>
        </District>
     </City>
 <AddressInfo>
```

I have tried specifying the InputStreamReader and the InputSource that feed the SAXParser, 
it didnT work:

```
    SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler();    
    SAXParser parser;
try {
      //dis is a DataInputStream
      parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();     
      InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(dis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
      inputSource.setCharacterStream(inputReader);
      inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    //ignoring the inputsource and using directly the DataInputStream
      parser.parse(dis, handler);   
    //also tried with inputSource, no joy
    //parser.parse(inputSource, handler);
```

....

What might be going wrong? Any ideas?

Cheers

*Note:* 
 The input xml does not have any declaration such as

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
```

Comment: What's the original encoding of your file? (and what does Utility.getEncoding() return?)

Answer (score 0):

Try Reading input as character stream and use Input source to encode. UTF-8 need's to be read character by character. InputStream can't be encoded as UTF-8.

Something like this will help you.
If you are parsing XML make sure you read clob as  Something.getcharacterStream();

```
Reader F;
F=clob.getcharacterStream(); (If getting clob from database make sure you are reading it as character stream)
BuffeReader Readfile = new BufferReader(F);
InputSource Encode = new InputSource(Readfile);
Encode.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```